# Dynamic v-model with v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, vue-component

I have a v-for loop that is going to spit out multiple rows of inputs that I would like to save each separate row to an array object dynamically.

v-for:

```
<table class="table m-0">
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="fund in defaultFunds">
      <td>
        {{fund.name}}
        <b-input v-model="newEntries[fund.id]['id']" 
                 :value="fund.id" 
                 name="entryFund" 
                 type="text" 
                 class="d-none" 
                 :key="fund.id" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <b-input v-model="newEntries[fund.id]['amount']" 
                 name="newFundAmount" 
                 id="newFundAmount" 
                 type="text" 
                 placeholder="Amount" 
                 :key="fund.id"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Desired array (using example of entering 2 rows):

```
newEntries: [
  { id: '1', amount: '50.00' },
  { id: '2', amount: '123.45' }
],
```

I load `newEntries` as an empty array by default. I don't know how to get the kind of array object I want with v-for. With the above code I end up with this:

```
newEntries: [null, '50.00', '123.45']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<tr v-for="fund in defaultFunds" :key="fund.id">` key should be in here, not in `b-input`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you want something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/e6L5seec/

```
<div id="app">
   newEntries: {{ newEntries }}
   <table>
      <tr v-for="(fund, index) in defaultFunds">
         <td>{{ fund.name }}</td>
         <td>
            <input    v-model="newEntries[index].id"
               name="entryFund"
               :value="fund.id"
               type="text"  />
         </td>
         <td>
            <input  v-model="newEntries[index].amount"
               name="entryFund" 
               type="text"  />
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
          defaultFunds: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: 'fund 0'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'fund 1'
      }
    ],
    newEntries: [{}, {}]
    }
  },
  methods: {
  }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly it, and I actually tried this but after compile, I get javascript errors in console saying that cannot read property 'id' of undefined; But in my vue inspector defaultFunds is most definitely defined

Comment: Is `defaultFunds`'s id start from 1? If yes, there will be an error. You need to use `newEntries[fund.id + 1].id` instead

Comment: defaultFunds ids can be any integer greater than 0. I have an axios call pulling them from a db so it can anything from 1 to infinity. It won't always start with 1, do I need to do the same thing with that?

Comment: If it's the case, you should use `v-for="(fund, index) in defaultFunds"`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @ittus! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The link example seems broken