# VueJs - Elemenet UI : How to set el-select option inside v-for

Tags: vuejs2, selecteditem, v-for, element-ui

I have packageData with item has children and doesn't have children, then step 1 is loop v-for packageData.items.data then each item have component el-select. But el-select show all data item every index.

Expected :

1. I want the el-select component only generates item data based on index

   example: LIST OF PACKAGE

   - Ipad = el-select (data index[0])
   - Iphone = el-select (data index[1])

2 . if item doesn't have children el-select generates item parent but if item has children el-select generates item with parent join item children

example: LIST OF PACKAGE

- Ipad = without children (option: item.data)
- Iphone = with children (option: item.data join item.data.children.data)

Here my code

```
<div class="row" v-for="(item, index) in packageData.items.data" :key="index">
  <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
     <h5>{{ item.product_group_name }}</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
   <el-select v-model="valuePackage" filterable placeholder="Select">
     <el-option v-for="list in packageData.items.data" :key="index" :label="list.product_name" :value="list.product_id">
     </el-option>
    </el-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

here my axios GET

```
getProductPackage() {
  let headers = {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + window.accessToken
  }
  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: baseApi(this.selectedStore.url_id, 'en', 'productpackage'),
    headers: headers
  })
    .then(response => {
      this.packageData= response.data.data
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
},
```

here my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dede402/5zw92gqm/37/

Answer (score 0):

You could map your array before render component in a Watch (if this variable is from another component) or in Mount event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Comment: i've update question with method GET, could you give me an example with 
 
.then(response => {
      this.packageData= response.data.data
    })

Answer (score 0):

You could set a dynamic value for the v-model in your data.

For example:

```
data() {
    return {
      item: [
         {
           id:'1234',
           itemName:'item1',
           persons: ["person1", "person2", "person3", "person4"]
         },
         {
           id:'4567',
           itemName:'item2',
           persons: ["person5", "person6", "person7", "person8"]
         }
      ],
      dynamicModel: {}
    };
  }
```

Then you can do this:

```
<tr v-for="item in items">
  <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
  <td v-for="person in items.persons">
   <input v-model="dynamicModel[person]"
     name="person"
     :value="person"       
     type="text" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510724/dynamic-v-model-with-v-for)

You can check [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/e6L5seec/) (you can find it in the post also)

Hope it helps...